# Relationship not returning any data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making a forums system with post likes, but for some reason, the relationship for the post likes doesn't return any data.

I have tried loading the data without the resource, and included with('all_likes') but this still doesnt return the data.

My get posts method:

```php
public function getPosts($id) 
{
    $response = array();
    $response['posts'] = ForumPostResource::collection(ForumPost::where('thread_id', $id)->get());

    return $response;
}
```

My Forum Post Resource:

```php
class ForumPostResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'thread_id' => $this->thread_id,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'like_data' => $this->all_likes,
            'user_data' => new UserResource($this->user),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at
        ];
    }
}
```

My forum post model:

```php
class ForumPost extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'thread_id', 'body', 'likes', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $appends = ['likes_total', 'user_data'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function all_likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostLike', 'id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return date('D, d F Y G:i', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function getUserDataAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user()->first();
    }

    public function getLikesTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->all_likes()->count();
    }
}
```

Once you click on the like button the user id and post id are added to the post_likes database. Then when the view is loaded which displays all forum posts including the post likes relationship data.

The result I get is this:

```php
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "user_id": 1501,
            "thread_id": 3,
            "body": "<p>Welcome everyone</p>",
            "like_data": [],
            "user_data": {
                "name": "mikelmao",
                "role_id": 1,
                "avatar": "users/default.png"
            },
            "created_at": "Sat, 05 January 2019 13:04",
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2019-01-11 03:22:27.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This should be returning 1 post like result as my db looks like this:

id|user_id|post_id

1|1501|14

Comment: `id`, `user_id`, and `post_id` are your post_likes table column, right?

Comment: A `ForumPost` has many `App\ForumPost`'s? Is this correct?

Comment: try doing  'id' => $request->id etc in FOrumPostResource

Comment: @n1njac0de Yes, thats the post_likes table

Comment: @RossWilson ah yeah this was definitely wrong. Though the problem is still occuring if i switch it to 'App\PostLike'

Comment: @Indra Im not sure what you mean, change $this with $resource? it gives error as $resource doesnt exist

Comment: public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $request->id,

Comment: If that is from your `post_likes` table, then I think you have to make many-to-many relation between `ForumPost` and `User` which I don't see at your code @MichaelGuimaraes

Comment: public function all_likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostLike', 'post_id', 'id'); // the method definition    public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    }

Comment: and also may I know why did you create `PostLike` model? Since it was supposed to be many-to-many pivot table. In Laravel you don't need to create model for many-to-many table

Comment: @n1njac0de you can create a model if you add extra columns, but it's a corner case. However it won't break your code if you add it just because you want to

Comment: @n1njac0de No, you don't need to but some people like this approach as it means (amongst other things) you can have more semantically correct controllers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI

Comment: for extra column I will prefer using `withPivot` helper. This also to avoid ambiguousity like this case

Comment: @indra if i change to $request it will return null for everything except for the id.

Comment: @n1njac0de i agree, but it does not break the code

Comment: @MichaelGuimaraes try changing the relation as I posed a few comments above. I think your params are in the wrong order

Comment: @n1njac0de I dont think it needs to be a many to many relationship. 1 post can have many post likes, and a like can only be on 1 post.

Comment: what does it mean with 'like'. It's from `user` to `post` right?

Comment: @n1njac0de haha ofcourse, the post_id is foreign key and id the local. This in combination with loading the wrong model fixed the problem. Very stupid of me xD I completely overlooked these things. Thank you guys so much :D

Answer (score 0):

I had overlooked the fact that it was calling `App\PostLike` and the foreign key and local key were in the wrong order.

Method definition is:

```
 public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
```